# Resize nodes bug

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs, konva

I have these sliders that will allow the shape to move over the canvas as well as change its width and height, but when I change the width or height of a shape its nodes that resize the shape increase in a different way then its should.

more over I am also looking for a way to do change in width and height in a way that the shapes area remain same, I was using boundBoxFunc for that but not able to pick the exact shape that I want.

I am trying to resize the rectangle using a input field such that when I change the width in input field it will change width of the rectangle.

```js
function resizeRect(shape, layer, stage) {

  var anchors = [];
  anchors[rect1._id] = ['top-center', 'middle-right', 'middle-left', 'bottom-center'];


  const MIN_HEIGHT = height[0]
  const MAX_HEIGHT = height[1]
  const MIN_WIDTH = width[0]
  const MAX_WIDTH = width[1]

  const tr = new Konva.Transformer({
    nodes: [shape],
    ignoreStroke: true,
    padding: 5,
    boundBoxFunc: function(oldBoundBox, newBoundBox) {

      // Looking for a way to make this avaiable only for certain shapes (Like I have 4 shapes two rectangle and two group rectangle in l-shaped)
      if (oldBoundBox.width != newBoundBox.width && oldBoundBox.height == newBoundBox.height) {
        // console.log("change in width")
        // pick shape if its rect1 change width also when changing height so equal area
      } else {
        // console.log("change in height")
        // pick shape if its rect1 change height also when changing width so equal area

      }

      return newBoundBox;
    },
  });

  tr.rotateEnabled(false);

  tr.nodes([])

  stage.on('click tap', function(e) {


    if (e.target.getName() == '') {
      tr.nodes([]);
      return;
    }

    const keyPressed = e.evt.shiftKey || e.evt.ctrlKey;
    const isSelected = tr.nodes().indexOf(e.target) >= 0;

    tr.enabledAnchors(anchors[e.target._id]);

    if (!keyPressed && !isSelected) {
      tr.nodes([e.target]);
    } else if (keyPressed && isSelected) {
      const nodes = tr.nodes().slice();
      nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(e.target), 1);
      tr.nodes(nodes);

    }
  });

  layer.add(tr);

}


var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'canvas',
  width: 512, // 4 CM = 128 PX/CM
  height: 896, // 7 CM = 128 PX/CM 
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();


// Inner Items
rect1X = 210;
rect1Y = 300;
rect1Width = 31;
rect1Height = 190;
$('#coil_1_x').val(rect1X)
$('#coil_1_y').val(rect1Y)
$('#coil_1_width').val(rect1Width)
$('#coil_1_height').val(rect1Height)

var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
  x: rect1X,
  y: rect1Y,
  width: rect1Width,
  height: rect1Height,
  name: 'rect1',
  fill: '#ec8e8e',
  stroke: '#ec8e8e',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  draggable: true
});

rect1.on('mouseover', function() {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});

rect1.on('mouseout', function() {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});

rect1.on('dragmove', function() {
  targetRect = rect1.getClientRect();
  $('#coil_1_x').val(targetRect.x)
  $('#coil_1_y').val(targetRect.y)
});

var oldRect1 = '';
rect1.on('transformstart', () => {
  oldRect1 = { ...rect1
  };
})

rect1.on('transform', function() {

  targetRect = rect1.getClientRect();
  rect1.setWidth(rect1.width() * rect1.scaleX());
  rect1.setHeight(rect1.height() * rect1.scaleY());
  $('#coil_1_width').val(Math.round(targetRect.width));
  $('#coil_1_height').val(targetRect.height);
  rect1.scaleX(1);
  rect1.scaleY(1);
});

$('#coil_1_x').keyup(function() {
  rect1.setX($(this).val());
});

$('#coil_1_y').keyup(function() {
  rect1.setY($(this).val());
});

$('#coil_1_width').keyup(function() {
  rect1.setWidth($(this).val());
  // if i do the changes in scaleX we got something like a really big width in thousands 
});

$('#coil_1_height').keyup(function() {
  rect1.setHeight($(this).val());
});


layer.add(rect1);

resizeRect(rect1, layer, stage);

stage.add(layer);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div id="canvas" class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div id="slider" class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Slider</h3>
          </div>

        </div>


        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="">Coil 1 X (Red)</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="coil_1_x">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="">Coil 1 Y</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="coil_1_y">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="">Coil 1 Width</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="coil_1_width">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="">Coil 1 Height</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="coil_1_height">
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@9/konva.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and not a good fit for SO. Try looking at the tutorials at https://konvajs.org/docs/ or ask on the konva discord channel https://discord.gg/pgBvbDfF